# Fill data into TextArea and jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help for fill a textarea with data recived from query DB. 
I have a dialog (Jquery) that contain another dialog and into this one, a textarea.

pseudocode:

```
<MODAL>
   <modalB>
     <TextArea>some data recibed</textarea>
   </modalB>
<MODAL>
```

When I call a function that opens the  the textarea return the result from a DB (as wished). The problem is when I close the  and open it up again, because the textarea returns empty. When I do it a second time, it works fine again (the textarea returns DB data).

javascript code:

```
function detalleSeguimiento(idSeguimiento) {
  var datos = {'idSeguimiento': idSeguimiento};
  $.get("detalleSeguimientosCargar.php", datos, function(data){
    $("#textAreaDetalleSeguimiento").html(data);
  });
  $('#modalDetalleSeguimiento').dialog({
    width:750,
    minHeight:400,
    modal: true,
    title: 'titulo',
    resizable: false,
  });
}
```

Thank you!

EDIT: Thanks CrisC for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wait for the data to return before creating the dialog:

```
function detalleSeguimiento(idSeguimiento) {
    var datos = {'idSeguimiento': idSeguimiento};
    $.get("detalleSeguimientosCargar.php", datos, function(data){
        $("#textAreaDetalleSeguimiento").html(data);
        $('#modalDetalleSeguimiento').dialog({width:750,
                                              minHeight:400,
                                              modal: true,
                                              title: 'titulo',
                                              resizable: false});
   });
}
```

Just move the dialog inside the `$.get` callback.

Comment: Omfg!!!! ..You are god, thanks, I spent hours with this.... Silly me. And you only needed half a minute, master!!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use promises and use callback for retrieve data when data retrieve the function will be call

and one more option is create eventlistner for receive data like data is avalaible the event is fire